# How to make a pretty HTML using sos jupyter notebook

Tags: python, html, r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I've tried everything. The coolest libraries out there (pretty-jupyter, quarto, rmarkdown,...) seem not to be working with sos-notebooks, it's really a pain. Any idea how to create a dynamic, pretty html file?

thanks